# How to use multi-word aliases in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

I have a command that I want to use an alias for, but the alias contains 2 words. When I try to use the alias, the command is not triggered. Is there a way for me to use an alias with multiple words?

Command code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["gn", "night night"]) #
async def goodnight(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await channel.send("@everyone Goodnight everyone!")
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have commands with spaces by creating a command group with a subcommand, e.g.

```py
@bot.group(aliases=["gn", "night"], invoke_without_command=True)
async def goodnight(ctx):
    await ctx.send("@everyone Goodnight everyone!")

@goodnight.command()
async def night(ctx):
    await ctx.send("@everyone Goodnight everyone!")
```

More details on `invoke_without_command` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke_without_command#discord.ext.commands.Group.invoke_without_command) and in the comments below.

I've looked through discussions in the discord.py discord server and I see no other ways to have spaces in commands.

Comment: `invoke_without_command=True` makes the `goodnight` command only get invoked if the `night` subcommand is not invoked. If `invoke_without_command` is set to False (or omitted) and the user uses the `night night` command, the message "Goodnight everyone!"  would appear twice. More details here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke_without_command#discord.ext.commands.Group.invoke_without_command